# Which ZooKeeper to use with Apache Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have seen that i can either
(1) Use the `ZooKeeper` that comes with `Kafka`, or
(2) Use the `ZooKeeper` from `Apache` itself.

Which is the preferred method(if there is one) and why? My use-case is for a small application, so it will be a 3 `ZooKeeper` ensemble/cluster. I am using `Window 10` for my test. The `ZooKeeper` version i am using is `3.5.6`. The `Apache Kafka` version i am using is `2.12-2.3.0`

**Note:**
I have tried both ways i.e (1) and (2), and both work.

#### UPDATE:

Found what i was looking for. For use case (2), if i want to use `Kafka 3.0.0`, *ideally*, i will use it with `Zookeeper 3.6.3` as that's what it has been tested with, as noted [here](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#upgrade_300_notable).

> ZooKeeper has been upgraded to version 3.6.3.

Comment: Is there a specific feature that newer Zookeeper has you need?

Comment: Hi @cricket_007, thanks for your reply, there is no specific feature, just wanted to test against the latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka is tested against the Zookeeper version it comes with.

If you want to upgrade, you'll need to verify Zookeeper itself is backwards compatible with older clients/protocols that Kafka may use.

Its unlikely that jumping from 3.4.x to 3.5.x is a compatible change, but if you stay within the same minor release, it should be fine

Comment: Hi @cricket_007, thanks for your reply, this is a valid point.I will test the 3.4.14 version. As a side-note, i interpret your reply as: Don't bother to get the Apache ZK, just use the one that comes with Kafka, as it has been `battle-tested`? Right?

Comment: As an update, I just finished testing with 3.4.14, but i am getting the same issue. But very valid point though.

Comment: Could you please clarify what issues those are? Note: Kafka itself is not tested on Windows.

Comment: I have posted it as a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58926477/testing-fail-over-on-kafka). Thanks cricket_007